# Where is the root in these words: miniature, minimal, minimize?

Tags: morphology

Is it possible to identify one and the same root MIN in all these words: Miniature, minimal, minimize, minimum  minor, minority, minus, minute ? From etymological point of view they all came from one Roman root, but what about Modern English? If we consider MIN as a common root for all these words in Modern English, how shall we treat the other components -im, -ute, -us in those words? As derivational suffixes (if yes, then for sure not in Modern English).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Even if they were derived from the same root in Latin, they came to English by different paths, migrating whatever suffixes they had into root somewhere along the way.

I'd speculate *Miniature* is probably a root by itself. I'd speculate that *minimum*, *minimal*, *minimize* have common root *minim* (or maybe *minimum* with possible dropping of *um* part to accommodate suffixes *-ize* and *-al*). *minor* and *minority* same way have common root *minor*; and *minus* and *minute* are roots by themselves.

Comment: Alas, this is not entirely correct. Many of those are ultimately from the same root.

Answer (score 7):

It turns out there are two unrelated roots:

There is the (modern) Portuguese/Galician river *Minho/Miño*, called *Minius* in Latin, probably from an unknown root in Iberian, which is assumed to be a language isolate, i.e. not at all related to surrounding languages. From this comes *miniature* and the modern English prefix *mini-*.

From classical Latin ***Minius*** "an Iberian river":

- → *minium* "cinnabar" (probably obtained from or near the river Minius)

  - → Postclass. Lat. *minio* "to colour something (red) with cinnabar, illustrate"

    - → *miniatura* "a colouring, illustration (typically small)"

      - → Eng. *miniature* "a small version of something".

        - → *mini-* "very small"

Then there is Proto-Indo-European ****m(e)i-*** "small" + suffix ****-nu*** (probably a verbal suffix):

- → PIE **minu-* "to lessen, reduce*

  - → Lat. *minus* "less", *minor* "less, smaller", *minimus* "least, smallest", *minister* "servant"

    - → Eng. *minus, minor, minuscule, minimize, minimal, minister*
  - → Lat. *(di)minuo* "lessen, decrease"

    - → Eng. *diminish, minute, mince*

In all these English words, only *-ize* and *-al* would seem able to produce new words in English; the rest are best considered purely Latin suffixes. English words using the Latin suffixes *-tus, -or, -us, -(i)mus,* and  *-ter* were generally taken from Latin (mostly through French), not formed in English.

Comment: "Isolate language" as "Isolating/analytic language" or simply "isolated"?

Comment: @Alenanno: Oops, I meant *language isolate*, a language not at all related to surrounding languages.

Answer (score 5):

The modern prefix *mini-* seems to come from the word **miniatura**, but the etymology keeps going back, linguistically speaking. Read all the answer, when you reach the end, it will take you back to this first part so you'll understand why "it comes from *miniatura*".

---

**Miniatura** comes from the Latin word **miniare**, which comes from **minio** (we can stop here, but it still goes back. I'll mention it if you're interested).

The *[Minio](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minio)*<sup>1</sup>, in chemistry, is the mixture of 2 molecules of monoxide and 1 molecule of lead bioxide, red-orange coloured, obtained from the [massicot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Massicot). This substance was used in Middle Ages in the "Art of miniatura".

The *miniatura* was the image painted, with extreme care for detail, to decorate the first letters of manuscripts, something like this:

[image]

In the italian wikipedia for "miniature", it says (I'll translate it):

> Starting from the XIV century, the spreading of such images of small dimension, contributed to make the word "miniature" indicate images, paintings and objects of *small dimensions*.

(1): The name comes from a river in Spain, called Minius.

---

*Minĭmu(m)* ("*piccolissimo*" = very small) is the superlative for *Mĭnus* ("*piccolo*" = small).

*Minority* and *minus* come from the Latin word *minor*, which means "smaller" or "less".

*Minute* comes from *minutus*, past participle of *mĭnŭĕre*, "to make small, to reduce, to shrink".

We can't consider "-ute" "-im" as separated suffixes, as you proposed, because those parts come from the original word.

I couldn't find any proof that all those words relate to each other, and at this point, I could only speculate. My speculation was that "minio" for miniature was the ultimate original word, but during my research, unexpectedly, Greek came into the show and this makes me doubt about my speculation. I'm sorry I can't help you further, hope this helps though. If something comes up, I'll make sure to tell you.

Comment: You can't be saying, that *mini* in *minimum* is actually a prefix?

Comment: No, in that case it's a word. I guess I forgot part of the question :D I'm still fixing it.

Comment: Fuf, don't scare me like this :P

Comment: @Philoto: This matter was harder than I expected. I'd need to dig into etymological books and explore every angle of the Linguistics department :D Although I can say that "minus", "minor" and "minio" are the "farthest" words I found, etymologically speaking.

Comment: @Alenanno Well, morphology of imported words, especially imported long ago from already dead or significantly changed languages is always hard :)

Comment: @Philoto I guess you're right... I didn't brought Greek into my answer because I didn't find any proof of that and it could have been wrong and misleading.

Comment: @philoto: "fuf"? I'm afraid to google it.

Comment: @Mitch it's a sigh of relief in russian :)

Comment: *Makes a note: do not use russian interjections in English speech...