# Is *-scule* in *minuscule* a suffix?

Tags: suffixes

Is *-scule*  in *minuscule* a suffix?

What does it mean? *scale*?

(I have looked it up in etymonline and didn't find the answer)

Comment: Related: [Where is the root in these words: miniature, minimal, minimize?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/29194/where-is-the-root-in-these-words-miniature-minimal-minimize)

Comment: The _-(c)ulus_ suffix is a Latin diminutive. _Opus_ means 'a work', _opusculus_ means 'a little work'.

Comment: @JohnLawler: Does  -(c)ulus in Latin correspond to -scule in English? Are there some good references for me to study the Latin suffix/roots and their corresponding English ones?

Comment: Lots of good examples for study at http://www.morewords.com/ends-with/cule/ and http://www.morewords.com/ends-with/culus/ and http://www.morewords.com/ends-with/cle/

Comment: @Tim: It doesn't "correspond to" -scule in English. It **is** -scule in English. The whole word, root and diminutive suffix, was borrowed as a piece into English, where you can see the fossil of the old suffix poking out. But it's not really an English suffix; it's not productive any more. It's just that English borrowed so many words (about half the vocabulary, one way or another) from Latin that there are a lot of English words with Latin suffixes sticking out of them.

Answer (score 8):

The word *minuscule* refers originally to small letters, and comes from Latin *minusculus*, which, [according to Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/minuscule) is a [diminutive form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diminutive#Latin) of *minor*. It is analogous to *majuscule*, which is a diminutive form of *major*. That is, the Latin comparative adjective *minor* meaning "smaller" has a diminutive form of *minusculus*. If there is any "suffix" here it would be the diminutive suffix *-culus* that is attached to *minus*, the neuter (or adverbial) form of *minor*.

After a quick search, almost all adjectives¹ on *-sculus* in Latin seem to be based on comparatives (like *longius/longiusculus, plus/plusculus,* etc.), so the rule appears to be that *-culus* is directly attached to the neuter/adverbial form of a comparative. With other words, *-culus* is normally attached by chopping off a final consonant group (if present) from the word and then using a a vowel that is in the last syllable, or *-i-*. The combination *verna + -culus* becomes *vernaculus*, *ferox + -culus* becomes *feroculus*, *annus + -culus* becomes *anniculus*.

The word *minuscule* is often misspelled as *miniscule*, on analogy from the derived prefix *mini-*, meaning small. But *mini-* comes from *miniature*, which comes from Italian *miniatura*, which refers to the art of illuminating a manuscript with colored inks. The derivation comes from Latin *miniatus*, which is the past participle of *miniare*, meaning "to color with minium", where *minium* is the Latin name for [red lead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_lead), a pigment used for illuminating manuscripts.

There is no etymological relationship of the word *minuscule* and *miniature*.

---

¹) All Latin adjectives on *-sculus* except one are based on neuter comparatives, in Cerberus' dictionary:

- altiusculus
- ampliusculus
- duriusculus
- frigidiusculus
- grandiusculus
- lautiusculus
- liquidiusculus
- longiusculus
- maiusculus
- meliusculus
- minusculus
- nitidiusculus
- plusculus
- putidiusculus
- salsiusculus
- suffusculus (the only exception: here *-c-* is part of the original adjectival stem, so this word has a different suffix, *-ulus*)
- tardiusculus
- unctiusculus

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/95?m=11539983#11539983

Comment: +1, but *minor* is an adjective and *minus* an adverb/adjective, not a noun.

Comment: @Cerberus I have no formal training in Latin, so please suggest a change to correct my error.

Comment: @nohat: I've added a bit of info on the nature and construction of words on *-usculus*. My edit was immediately applied; if you think it draws too much attention to the Latin, feel free to revert or prune. Especially the appendix might be a bit too much...I don't know, I thought it might be interesting.

Comment: @Cerberus we'll just call the answer a joint effort, a little bit of you and a little bit of me.

Comment: @nohat: Woohoo! Most of our baby is yours, though, for the record.