# How to find words which are related morphologically?

Tags: grammar, etymology, parts-of-speech, dictionaries, morphology

I'm looking for a book, or any other source, which lists words that are morphologically related, like this:

```
imagine        verb
imagination    noun
imaginative    adjective
```

Or this:

```
medic          noun
medicine       noun
medical        adjective
medicinal      adjective
```

And also this kind of relationship:

```
head           noun
ahead          adverb, adjective
```

Dictionaries will give you only partial information, and in a very inconvenient way.
For example, if you look at the definition of *imagination*, the words *imagine* and *imaginative* are not mentioned there, nor any reference to them. I've checked several dictionaries, and you may be lucky with other ones, but I have not found one which lists all the relevant information in a straightforward manner.

Etymology dictionary is also not suitable for this task. It doesn't give you all the relevant forms of the word, and it does give historical information which is not relevant here.

Comment: The normal layout of dictionaries (words listed in alphabetical order) doesn't exactly seem "inconvenient" to me. OED has about 30 words before and after the word "imagine" that all start with the same 6 letters - I'm not going to check them all, but I imagine most if not all are ***etymologically*** related.

Comment: The [Online Etymology Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?l=m&p=19&allowed_in_frame=0) is readily available, and cross-references closely related words in red, so links such as you require are very easy to pick out.

Comment: There is OneLook's wildcard feature, where you can look up [imagin*](http://www.onelook.com/?w=imagin*&scwo=1&sswo=0) or [medic*](http://www.onelook.com/?w=medic*&loc=scworef&scwo=1&ls=a).

Comment: This looks like a good question for meta.

Comment: I remember seeing a similar question on ELU not that long ago. Somebody had provided an interesting link that might fit your request.

Comment: Can you please speficy what the "several dictionaries" were? I actually have trouble thinking of many dictionaries that do not cross-link to derived words, or even list their definitions right there on the same page. Also, you mean "morphologically", not "grammatically". The word *imagine* is not grammatically related to anything, not even to itself.

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/29194/where-is-the-root-in-these-words-miniature-minimal-minimize?rq=1 This has an interesting slant as to how relevant it might be knowing or guessing the root word. Sometimes, common sense alone doesn't cut it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Word by letter**](http://www.wordbyletter.com/prefixe.php)

Type the beginning of a word and just see how many results are churned out.

> ENGLISH WORDS STARTING WITH "MEDIC"
>
> medic, medicable, medicably, medicaid, medicaids, medical, medically,
>   medicals, medicament, medicamental, medicaments, medicant, medicare,
>   medicares, medicaster, medicate, medicated, medicates, medicating,
>   medication, medications, medicative, medicator, medicean, medicinable,
>   medicinal, medicinally, medicine, medicined, medicines, medicining,
>   medicks, medico, medicommissure, medicornu, medicornua, medicos,
>   medics,

[**Your Dictionary**](http://definitions.yourdictionary.com/)

Has a more traditional approach but its resources are reliable;
[medic](http://www.yourdictionary.com/medic#websters)

**Wordnet** Click on any link and all will be revealed. Pretty amazing stuff, I say so myself.
[**medicine**](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?o2=&o0=1&o8=1&o1=1&o7=&o5=&o9=&o6=&o3=&o4=&s=medicine&i=6&h=100001000000000#c)

**Word Info** has a box with the suffixes and the root word of imagination. Click on *imag* and *imagi* and a new page will open with a fair list of derivatives. 
[imaginative](http://wordinfo.info/results?searchString=imagination)

- *image*

  1. A reproduction of the form of a person or object, especially a sculptured likeness.
     etc..
- *imageable* (adjective)
- *imageless*
- *imager*
- *imagery*
- *imaginable* (adjective)
- *imaginably*
- *imaginant*
- *Imagining*
- *imaginary*
- *imaginarily*
- *imaginariness*
- *imagination*
  (list of definitions)
- *imaginative*
  (list of definitions)
- *imaginatively*
- *imagine*

Comment: Ok, but as an ESL, suppose you know the word *imaginative*, and don't know that the the root is *imag*, so you will not search for *imagin**. The closest I have found is this: http://www.learnenglish.org.uk/wff/  . If I will not find exactly what I want I will except your answer.

Comment: Just to clarify myself: If an ESL know what *imaginative* means, he does not necessarily know that the word is derived from *image*, *imagine*, etc.

Comment: This will probably be true for speakers of non-[Romance languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romance_languages) and it's a valid point. But a decent monolingual dictionary under *imaginative* will provide the adverbial expression, *imaginatively*;  the adjective form, *imaginative*; idiomatic expressions such as *"a figment of sb's imagination"* ---> see *figment*; *the mind/imagination boggles* ---> see *boggle*; *not by any stretch of the imagination* ---> see *stretch* And nothing stops you from reading the words that precede and follow, imagination.

Comment: In the age of high technology, and the frenzy to have all the answers within the click of a mouse; this has meant that the humble reference book is losing favour and popularity among learners. But this is a mistake, open a dictionary and on one page there will be a wealth of other information, details, expressions, curiosities, and the like which you will miss out by studying exclusively online. Your eye will glance down the page and spot something interesting which might never have occurred with a digital format.

Comment: Check [*imaginative*](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/imaginative) . The words *imagination* or *imagine* are not mentioned anywhere. Or search for *medicine* in Merriam-Webster College. *Medical* is not mentioned. But you are right that with *detective work* I can gather most of the information. I guess.

Comment: It's not so much lexical as it really is derivational-morphological. http://www.morewords.com/starts-with/med/ vs. http://www.morewords.com/starts-with/medic

Comment: One pitfall: **medick** *US*, **medic** [ˈmɛdɪk] n (Life Sciences & Allied Applications / Plants) any small leguminous plant of the genus *Medicago*, such as black medick or sickle medick, having yellow or purple flowers and trifoliate leaves [from Latin *mēdica*, from Greek *mēdikē* (*poa*) Median (grass), a type of clover]  (TFD)

Answer (score 1):

*[Generate Derivational Variants, Recursively](http://lexsrv3.nlm.nih.gov/LexSysGroup/Projects/lvg/2008/docs/designDoc/UDF/flow/fR.html)*

> medicine|medicality|128|1|R|1|RULE|medical|medicality|$|adj|base|ity$|noun|base|dd|NounAdj|
>   medicine|medicative|128|1|R|1|RULE|medicate|medicative|ate$|verb|base|ative$|noun|base|ddddd|NotNounAdj|
>   medicine|medication|128|1|R|1|RULE|medic|medication|$|verb|base|ation$|noun|base|ddddd|NotNounAdj|
>   medicine|medic|128|1|R|1|RULE|medical|medic|al$|adj|base|$|noun|base|dd|NounAdj|
>   medicine|medicant|128|1|R|1|RULE|medic|medicant|$|verb|base|ant$|noun|base|ddddd|NotNounAdj|
>   medicine|medicate|1024|1|R|1|RULE|medicable|medicate|able$|adj|base|ate$|verb|base|dddd|NotNounAdj|
>   medicine|medic|1024|1|R|1|RULE|medicable|medic|able$|adj|base|$|verb|base|dddd|NotNounAdj|
>   medicine|medicinally|2|1|R|1|RULE|medicinal|medicinally|$|adj|base|ly$|adv|base|dd|NotNounAdj|
>   medicine|medically|2|1|R|1|RULE|medical|medically|$|adj|base|ly$|adv|base|dd|NotNounAdj|
>   medicine|medicinal|1|1|R|1|RULE|medicine|medicinal|e$|noun|base|al$|adj|base|d|NounAdj|
>   medicine|medicant|1|1|R|1|RULE|medic|medicant|$|verb|base|ant$|adj|base|ddddd|NotNounAdj|
>   medicine|medical|1|1|R|1|FACT|medicine|noun|medical|adj|d|NounAdj|
>   medicine|medicable|1|1|R|1|RULE|medic|medicable|$|noun|base|able$|adj|base|ddd|NounAdj|

The link to the java source code is provided on that page; also visit the home page. Can that help?

Comment: Very interesting, but an overkill. I will not learn Java for this.. Anyway +1.

Comment: @Bohoo Incidentally, not everyone that uses java applets (which is quite everyone who uses a computer, no exaggeration) needs to know java. Anyways, we are still researching for the root-to-derivations lists that some good Samaritan *must* have done already.